# Doctrine Cache fails after migration

Tags: php, caching, doctrine, laminas

I wrote a PHP application using Doctrine for database management and Laminas for REST API. It's a project I'm currently migrating, so Doctrine from version 3 to 5 and Laminas Cache from 2 to 3.

The configuration file for Doctrine looks like this:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidBinaryType;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Doctrine\UuidType;

return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver::class,
                'params' => [
                    'url' => getenv('MYSQL_URL'),
                    'serverVersion' => getenv('MYSQL_VERSION'),
                ],
                'doctrine_type_mappings' => [
                    'bit' => Types::BOOLEAN,
                    UuidType::NAME => UuidType::NAME,
                    UuidBinaryType::NAME => Types::BINARY,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'configuration' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'generate_proxies' =>
                    false !== getenv('DOCTRINE_AUTOGENERATE_PROXY_CLASSES')
                        ? filter_var(getenv('DOCTRINE_AUTOGENERATE_PROXY_CLASSES'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)
                        : true,
                'query_cache' => false !== getenv('DOCTRINE_CACHE_QUERY')
                    ? getenv('DOCTRINE_CACHE_QUERY')
                    : 'zendblackhole',
                'result_cache' => false !== getenv('DOCTRINE_CACHE_RESULT')
                    ? getenv('DOCTRINE_CACHE_RESULT')
                    : 'zendblackhole',
                'metadata_cache' => false !== getenv('DOCTRINE_CACHE_METADATA')
                    ? getenv('DOCTRINE_CACHE_METADATA')
                    : 'zendblackhole',
                'hydration_cache' => false !== getenv('DOCTRINE_CACHE_HYDRATION')
                    ? getenv('DOCTRINE_CACHE_HYDRATION')
                    : 'zendblackhole',
                'types' => [
                    UuidType::NAME => UuidType::class,
                    UuidBinaryType::NAME => UuidBinaryType::class,
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'zendblackhole' => [
                'class' => \DoctrineModule\Cache\LaminasStorageCache::class,
                'instance' => 'zend-blackhole',
            ],
            'zendmemcache' => [
                'class' => \DoctrineModule\Cache\LaminasStorageCache::class,
                'instance' => 'zend-memcache',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

The configuration file for Laminas Cache looks like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'api-tools-cache' => [
        'zend-blackhole' => [
            'adapter' => \Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\BlackHole::class,
        ],
        'zend-memcache' => [
            'adapter' => \Laminas\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Memcached::class,
            'options' => [
                'servers' => [
                    explode(':', getenv('MEMCACHE_SERVER')),
                ],
                'namespace' => 'my-app',
            ],
            'plugins' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'exception_handler',
                    'options' => [
                        'throw_exceptions' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Everything worked perfectly in the old application. When I start the migrated application, I now get the following error message:

"TypeError: DoctrineModule\Cache\LaminasStorageCache::__construct(): Argument #1 ($storage) must be of type Laminas\Cache\Storage\StorageInterface, string given"

What have I configured incorrectly or ignored?

Answer (score 0):

Since the version 3 of `laminas/laminas-cache` came up there were some bc breaks. I guess one of them hits your migration. The aliases for the different cache adapters have been changes. Though it passes the string `zend-blackhole` to the `LaminasStorageCache` class constructor which results into an exception. In your case `zendblackhole` has to be changed into `blackhole`.

If you look into `\DoctrineModule\Service\CacheFactory` in line 50:

```
...
if (is_string($instance) && $container->has($instance)) {
   $instance = $container->get($instance);
}
...
```

The laminas service manager tries to get an instance of your cache storage adapter. In your case it can 't, because aliases like `zend-blackhole` or `zendblackhole` are not registered in the laminas cache config. You have to use `blackhole` or `filesystem` or `memcache`.

Always remember, that the different storage adapters have moved into different new storage adapter packages you have to require first:

`$ composer require laminas/laminas-cache-storage-adapter-blackhole`

Comment: Hm, I once changed the instance key to 'blackhole' in the Doctrine config and of course also in the Laminas config. However, the application still dies with the same error that I passed a string instead of an object. Maybe the Doctrine cache isn't compatible with Laminas Cache 3 at all?

Comment: Can you check what string exactly triggered the error? The reason for the thrown exception is this string which is not registered as alias in the service manager config. When you are using XDebug just set a stop point in \DoctrineModule\Service\CacheFactory at line 50.

Comment: It's "zend-blackhole". I changed it also to "blackhole" or "api-tools-cache.zend-blackhole".

Comment: "zend-blackhole" and "api-tools-cache.zend-blackhole" are wrong. Every cache config related to laminas/laminas-cache should be "blackhole".

Comment: Hm, you mean "blackhole" as an alias for BlackHole::class? But in my case it's a config-key and you can usually name it whatever you want, because it's linked to the correct adapter. But apart from that: As I said - "blackhole" as an instance value doesn't work either.

Comment: As long as it results in a non-existent alias in the factory, it is not a freely selectable value.